# When I execute a Math.random() function why is it able to return "1" when "1" is exclusive?

Tags: javascript, function, random, max, min

When I call the randomNumber() function below it always prints out "1" to the console. This was confusing to me because I thought that "0" was inclusive and "1" was exclusive. If the range was "0" to "1", wouldn't randomNumber() never return "1"? Why is the program doing that?

Here is the relevant code:

```
function randomNumber(min,max) {
         return Math.random()* (max-min) + min;
}

var rand= Math.ceil(randomNumber(0,1));

console.log(rand);
```

Comment: It's not the `random` function, it's `Math.ceil` -- put in 0.00001 and you'll still get 1 when you execute the ceil function.

Comment: because of `Math.ceil()`.

Comment: Mathematically speaking, it doesn't make much difference if it is inclusive or exclusive: random from `(0,1)` is basically the same as random from `[0,1]`. The event of getting exactly `0` or `1` has probability zero, although it could still happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `rand` is not the output of the random number generator; it is the *ceiling* of the output, which is defined as the smallest integer that is larger than or equal to the output. In your case, that's 1.

Try this instead:

```
function randomCharge(min,max) {
    return Math.random()* (max-min) + min;
}

var rand= randomCharge(0,1);

console.log(rand);
```